# Given two positive real numbers $A$ and $l$, does there exist a plane, closed, simple curve with area $A$ and length $l$?

Tags: geometry, area, differential

We are given two real positive numbers $A$ and $l$, such that $4\pi A \leqslant l^2$ (so the Isoperimetric inequality holds). Is it true we can always find a plane, simple, closed curve so that curve has length $l$ and region that it encloses has area $A$ ? If not, give a counterexample.

Intuitively, I think it is true, but I'm not sure have to define the curve with given properties.

Comment: Heuristic hint: I would use a construction which is valid for any $A,l$. Now, if $l^2/A$ is very close to $4 \pi$, the construction should give a curve very similar to a cirlce. So, I suggest to construct the curve starting by a circle and then modify it in some way. For example we could consider curves formed by a circle arc and a chord.

Comment: Heuristic: suppose you’re given $A$ and $l$ as described. Form a circle centered at the origin of perimeter $l$ (which has area greater than or equal to $A$). Now stretch the circle in the positive $x$ direction. The perimeter will stay the same but the area will decrease to $0$, so by the IVT, must equal $A$ at some point.

Answer (score 3):

The area of an ellipse with radii $a$ and $\frac A{\pi a}$ is $A$. If we let $a$ vary continuously over the interval $[\sqrt{\frac A\pi},\infty)$, i.e. from  a circle to an arbitrarily stretched almost-line, the perimeter varies accordingly (and as a continuous function of $a$) over $[2\sqrt{\pi A},\infty)$.

---

If you want something more constructive, as shape like below (with a part of a circle pushed up by some distance $a$), can give you curves with area $A=\pi r^2$ and perimeter $\ell = 2\pi r+4a$ where you can easily pick $a$ arbitrarily in $[0,2r)$, i.e., this covers the cases
$$ 4\pi \le \frac{\ell^2}{A}<\frac{(2\pi+8)^2}{\pi}=64.9382\ldots$$
So for $\frac{\ell^2}A$ in that range, simple pick $r$, compute the desired $a$, and construct the figure accordingly - with the middle part thin enough to avoid problems, namely if the width of the middle part is $b$, you want $a^2+b^2<4r^2$.

On the other hand, $x\times y$ rectangles with $x\le y$ cover the cases $\frac{\ell^2}A\ge 16$. for given $\frac{\ell^2}A$, it is straightforward to compute $y$ for given $x$, say, from a quadratic equaiton.
[image]

Comment: How do I formally show that perimeter varies accordingly? Should I show that the integral of norm of speed is an increasing function as a function of $a$ when I parametrize ellipse as $c(t)=(a \cos(t),\frac{A}{\pi a}\sin(t))$

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = \frac12\sqrt{\ell^2-4\pi A}$ and $r = \frac1{2\pi}(\ell - 2s)$.

Start from a circle of radius $r$, cut it along a diameter into two semicircles. Insert a $(2r) \times s$ rectangle between the "cut" and glue the two semi-circles to the two sides of rectangle with length $2r$. You obtain a "pill"-like figure of area $A$ and perimeter $\ell$.

The algebra is left as an exercise.